# How can the magentic flux be determined in a transformer with airgap?

Tags: transformer, flux

I am planning to conduct chemical reactions in an AC magnetic field at 60Hz. The magnetic setup is made of two 1.4kW microwave transformers with HV coils and Iron I-cores removed. Then the two remaining E-cores are mounted facing each other leaving an airgap of 1mm in the center branch as the reaction cell. The AC mag field is controlled with a Variac to max 230VAC driving a coil with N=160 turns. The average magnetic iron path in this design is 30cm. The packing height is 7cm. Iron cross section is 15cm^2.
How can I calculate or measure (O-scope) the max magnetic field flux B [T] that can be expected for this set-up?
Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: You mean flux density, not flux. Flux is simply the integral of the applied voltage over time.

Comment: The simplest is to take a hall probe and measure it right inside the gap.

Comment: I took the SI definition for Tesla from Wiki [Wb/m^2], Wb being [Vs]. Essentially I am interested if my set-up will provide sufficeint 'magnetic effect' to show a change in a chemical reaction. (@Janka1)

Comment: Hall probe works for AC? Sorry, but I am just a chemist infringing onto EE territory. From my brief reading, transformer iron saturates at about 2 Tesla without an air gap. The question is now: How much lower will the max B amplitude be if a 1mm airgap is introduced. (@tobalt)

Comment: @ChrisOe The air gap will decrease B by a ratio of \$\frac{l_m}{l_m+\mu_r\,\cdot \,l_g}\$. Where \$l_g=1\:\text{mm}\$ is the air gap length and \$l_m=30\:\text{cm}\$ is the mean iron magnetic path length measured with a ruler, in this case, I guess. You need to provide \$\mu_r\$. Figure out B for the case without the air gap, first, of course.

Comment: @ChrisOe the Hall effect responds very quickly, many orders of magnitude faster than 60 Hz. Just pass a constant current through the Hall probe and measure its voltage. At this low frequency you can even measure the 60 Hz Hall voltage with a multimeter set to AC voltage (in case you cant get hold of a gaussmeter). If that fails, you can also measure the field at DC using the peak current though the coils.

Comment: @ChrisOe the \$B_{saturation}\$ of the iron core won't change with an air gap. Your gap-to-crosssection ratio is very small, so the gap field will be essentially the same as the iron internal B. However, you will magnetize the core (and gap) less with the same current, because the air gap increases the *reluctance* of the inductor. This is what jonk describes. For a given current which establishes a certain B in the ungapped core, the B in the gapped core will be reduced via his formula. But you can still achieve the original B, albeit using more current.